# Windows 7 XP Mode files lost in upgrade to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-xp-mode, windows-7-upgrade

I finally set aside the time to do my Windows 10 upgrade from Windows 7 at the weekend. 4 hours later it all seemed successful apart from a little glitch (which is now fixed) in terms of the PC not shutting down.
However one thing I didn't think in advance about was the XP Mode I used for some old software. 
Today, I used Hyper V to set up a XP Mode on Windows 10 but can't find all the data and programs that were available in XP Mode on Windows 7. Could I have lost them? I don't have any sort of back up for the data I had on the Windows 7 XP Virtual disk - more fool me.
I have found one *.vhd file on the C: drive but this is dated 2009 and so I figure that this is not much use. I can't link it in the Hyper V set-up anyway as it is Read Only and can't be changed, even with Administrator's privileges.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XP mode VM is stored in AppData (`%LocalAppData%/Microsoft/Windows Virtual PC/Virtual Machines/Windows XP Mode.vhd` to be specific).

There is a whole Microsoft article on how to recover your XP mode data if you upgraded to Windows 8 or 10. The gist of the article is to right click the VHD file, choose the `Mount` option and then browse the files inside.

Here's the article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2724115

Comment: Many thanks for this. That file mounted successfully and it looks like everything is still there. What I now need to do is link that VHD file to Hyper V and hopefully I will have everything as it was in XP Mode on Windows 7. I won't have time to have a crack at this until next week but am hopeful that I will have access online to the info I need to make this a success.